# MySQL: Join on most recent date

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table containing dates and a value:

```
table_1
-------
dt           x
2018-01-01   1
2018-01-06   4
2018-01-07   2
2018-01-12   3
```

And I have another table containing dates:

```
table_2
-------
dt
2018-01-01
2018-01-03
2018-01-04
2018-01-06
2018-01-08
2018-01-09
2018-01-11
```

I want to create a new table `my_joined_table` that

- contains all dates from `table_2` and
- for each date, contains the most recent value of `table_1.x` that is not newer than the date in the given row

So the result should be:

```
my_joined_table
---------------
dt           x
2018-01-01   1
2018-01-03   1
2018-01-04   1
2018-01-06   4
2018-01-08   2
2018-01-09   2
2018-01-11   2
```

This is probably a standard problem, but I cannot seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will give you the result you want. It `JOIN`s table_2 to table_1 on table_1 having the maximum `dt` less than or equal to the table_2 `dt` value:

```
SELECT t2.dt, t1.x
FROM table_2 t2
JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.dt <= t2.dt)
```

Output:

```
dt          x
2018-01-01  1
2018-01-03  1
2018-01-04  1
2018-01-06  4
2018-01-08  2
2018-01-09  2
2018-01-11  2
```

To create your `my_joined_table` table, just use a [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html) query:

```
CREATE TABLE my_joined_table AS
SELECT t2.dt, t1.x
FROM table_2 t2
JOIN table_1 t1 ON t1.dt = (SELECT MAX(dt) FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.dt <= t2.dt)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=896de92bcb27cfe8e9d5eaee88e2cfe9)